# How to make webClient.DownloadFile working?

Tags: download, webclient

This is my Code when clicked on Link Button:

```
protected void btnDownload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string url = "https://ppespcollab.amat.com/sites/IMDb/Shared Documents/LatestTest_IMDb_LPDetails_Template.xlsx";

        string file_name = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Sample.xlsx"; ;
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        webClient.DownloadFile(url, @file_name);
        webClient.Dispose();
}
```

There are no errors shown. But its not downloading. I'm Clueless. Tried different ways. Nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code**. Please post your code which gives an error so someone can have a look at it.

Comment: I have posted. There are no errors whatsoever.